# XCode Socket.io Swift: Type 'SocketEngine' does not conform to protocol 'WebSocketDelegate'

Tags: swift, xcode, socket.io

I installed the Socket.io Client Swift module in XCode, and when i try to build, it gives me this error:

> Type 'SocketEngine' does not conform to protocol 'WebSocketDelegate'

- XCode 15 Beta 4
- Project min iOS version: 15.0
- Socket.io Client Swift version: 16.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is the same situation as yours, but in my case I was able to build with the following.
Change starscream 4.0.6 to 4.0.4.

Comment: How did you downgrade it?

Comment: @Noel If you're using cocoapods as your package manager, try adding this line `pod 'Starscream', '4.0.4'` in your Podfile, and then run `pod update`

Comment: I'm using the built in depedencies. Successfully downgraded startscream to 4.0.4, but after running the app in emulator, i get a blank screen, sometimes loads in, but the log does not show any error or success

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. The fix is applied and already merged here
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/commit/d7846b31a215211e595292425a2fdd6d16177faf